# VirtualBoxで仮想ゲストとしてUbuntuをインストールし、 Windows10ホストからssh接続

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, virtualbox

VirtualBox 6.1.16で仮想ゲストとしてUbuntu 20.04.2 LTSをインストールした
Windows 10 Home 20H2 からゲストにssh接続が出来ていません。

#### 質問内容

systemdにsshのためのUnit設定ファイルを定義しようとしています。
ファイルの配置が間違っているのかと思うのですが、どこが間違っているか悩んでいます。

以下①、②を試しましたがうまくいきません。
①はじめ、Unit設定ファイルとしてsshd.serviceを以下に配置しました。
/etc/systemd/system

しかし
$ systemctl start sshd.service
と実行すると、
Failed to start sshd.service: Unit sshd.service is masked.
となります。

$ systemctl unmask sshd.service
を実行するとremovedとなり、Unitファイルが/etc/systemd/system
から削除されました。

②次に、/usr/lib/systemd/system
ディレクトリにsshd.serviceのファイルを配置し、
/etc/systemd/system
下にコピーしました。

それでも①と同じく、sshd起動コマンドを実行するとmaskedとなり、
unmaskしても設定ファイルが削除されてしまいます。

#### 事前におこなっていたこと

VirtualBoxでホストオンリー、ブリッジアダプターを設定済みです。

また、ssh_configにSSHを許可する設定を追加しました。
/etc/ssh/ssh_config の最後に以下の設定を追加

```
Port 22
PermitRootLogin no
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

以上でございます。情報提供をして頂けますと幸いでございます。

Comment: 「sshのためのUnit設定ファイルを定義しようとしています」とのことですが、openssh-server パッケージに含まれている unit ファイル(`/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service`)を使わずに自分で作成したということでしょうか?

Comment: 調べていると、おっしゃるとおりopenssh-server パッケージで公開っぽい設定ファイルがあるようですね。自作できるほど詳しくは理解が足りないため、opensshの方を使おうと思っています。

Comment: 「SSH を許可する設定を ssh_config に追加」とありますが、ssh**d**_config と ssh_config は別物になるので、間違いないか確認してみてください。

Answer (score 0):

以下を実行するだけでつながるはずです。

```
apt -y install openssh-server
systemctl restart ssh
```

※/etc/ssh/sshd_configを修正してrootのログインを禁止するなどの設定は別途しておいた方がいいです。

ホストオンリーアダプタのネットワークアドレスのIPでssh接続します。
※NATネットワークのネットワークアドレスのIPではssh接続できませんでした。
※ブリッジはホストOSのネットワークに参加してしまうため使ったことがありません。

【追記】
私の環境はVMのIPを手動で設定しています。※ホストオンリーアダプタのネットワークアドレスに所属するIPを指定

ホストOSのIPは別のネットワークアドレスなので、以下のようにルーティングしています。

```
route add -p ホストオンリーアダプタのネットワークアドレス/24 ホストオンリーアダプタのIP
```

試しにルーティングを削除したらホストからssh接続できなくなったので補足しておきます。